# SUMIFS with AND and OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I've tried, I think most of the answers here, but I can not get them to work in my situation.

Translated to text, my problem would looked like this :

Sum Y:Y column with

- condition 1 : Column B:B if string starts with "15*"
- condition 2 : Column T:T must be greater then 0
- condition 3 : OR (value from column U:U = 0 OR U:U > V:V )

Put in `SUMIFS` function, in theory, it would looked like this `SUMIFS(Y:Y,B:B,"15*",T:T,">0",or(U:U,"=0", U:U>V:V))`,
but of course it doesn't work like that.

Also I've tried `SUMPRODUCT` and `SUM(SUMIF`...but I don't know how to translate what I like to accomplish into these two.

So please, if someone knows how to make this work. And some explanation please.

Thanks.

Comment: can values in column V be negative?

Comment: ...and what sort of values are in column B - are they numbers or alphanumeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's SUMPRODUCT based solution which shall work for you.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(B:B,2)="15"),--(T:T>0),((U:U=0)+(U:U>V:V)),Y:Y)`

**Caution:** Apply complete column references only if necessary as it will slow down your sheet considerably. It is advisable to have a sufficiently large range (but not whole column references) as each column will have million cells to check.

**Also note** Barry's query about column V being negative has significance on the formula I have posted as it will calculate 2 TRUE conditions as 2 and therefore lead to erroneous result.

Comment: Note that the third "--" is redundant because the + between the next two conditions co-erces anyway.....

Comment: Thank you Shrivallabha Redij, I don't usually use SUMPRODUCT so I didn't use "--" in my attempt. I guess I have to learn that now :) Anyway, what about dynamic range like this : =SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(INDIRECT("B2:B"&Z1),2)="15"),--(INDIRECT("T2:T"&Z1)>0),((INDIRECT("U2:U"&Z1)=0)+(INDIRECT("U2:U"&Z1)>INDIRECT("V2:V"&Z1))),INDIRECT("Y2:Y"&Z1)) where Z1 = SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($B:$B<>"")*ROW($B:$B))). I know that INDIRECT will slow calculations down...What would that be faster then putting whole column in SUMPRODUCT?

Comment: @Jovica I will use INDEX rather than using volatile INDIRECT it will look then like `=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(B2:INDEX(B:B,Z1),2)="15"),--(T2:INDEX(T:T,Z1)>0),((U2:INDEX(U:U,Z1)=0)+(U2:INDEX(U:U,Z1)>V2:INDEX(V:V,Z1))),Y2:INDEX(Y:Y,Z1))`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this like this:

**1. Add new column for your condition 3**

Use another column, for example Z:Z wher you can put condition3.
For example, formula in `Z2=OR(U2>0;U2;V2)`.

This formula will give you values `TRUE` or `FALSE` as a result.

**2. Then you can base condition 3 on values in new column**

Now you `SUMIFS` formula can be:
`=SUMIFS((Y:Y;B:B;"15*";T:T;">0";Z:Z;TRUE)`

I checked this on your example and it works.